# Not clickable inputfields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clickable

Check http://student.howest.be/sylvain.vansteelandt/fedex/.
If you click on "Create a shipment" you will notice the first 4 inputfields are not clickable. How is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking how to disable the inputs like in that example, or why those inputs are disabled and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect the element you will see this:

```
<div class="eid_1377803337429_delivery_streetfield_id" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; left: 250px; top: 165px; width: 248px; height: 24px; right: auto; bottom: auto; font-family: source-sans-pro,sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 300; text-decoration: none; font-style: normal; text-align: left; opacity: 0; display: block;" id="eid_1377803337429_delivery_streetfield">
    <input class="createinput" id="delivery_streetinput" size="20" style="font-family:source-sans-pro" type="text">
</div>
```

Notice in the div that the opacity is set to 0:

```
opacity: 0;
```

You are still typing in the box, try typing and then going to the next screen, it's there. Due to opacity: 0, you just can't see it. Make this 100 instead of 0 and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

A disabled input element is unusable and un-clickable.

use disabled input as in

```
  // remember to add 'disabled' to input element
  <input type="text" name="some-name" disabled />
```

Comment: OP is asking why he cannot enter anything in the textbox not how to disable it.

Comment: @srijan Interesting! And I thought I cannot enter anything in disabled input.